# parse float in string in javascript

Tags: javascript

Say `str = 'translate(-100.93,50.88)'`, how can I get the two float: `-100.93` and `50.88` in JavaScript? I was stuck here for a while. I tried

```
str.match(/[\-|\+|\d+|\.]/g)
```

which gave me single chars.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
str = str.replace(/[a-zA-Z()]+/g, '').split(',');

var float1 = parseFloat(str[0]),
    float2 = parseFloat(str[1]);
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/sL6sV/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = 'translate(-100.93,50.88)';
var result = str.split(/,|\(|\)/);

alert(parseFloat(result[1])); // -100.93
alert(parseFloat(result[2])); // 50.88
```

Answer (score 0):

use a regular expression, such as:

```
var testString = 'translate(-100.93,50.88)'
var matches = testString.match(/translate\(([-.\d]+),([-.\d]+)/);

//(matches[0] is the first part of the string)
var num1 = matches[1]*1;
var num2 = matches[2]*1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = 'translate(-100.93,50.88)'        
var arr = str.match(/\(([^\(\,]+)\,([^\)]+)\)/);
var firstVal = arr[1];
var secVal = arr[2];
```